# What does 批 mean here?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I came across this sentence in 天橋上的魔術師 by 呉明益.

> 「不是，我是魔術師。」男人自己這樣宣稱。有一天我問他東西是哪裡**批**來賣的時候，他說，「這些魔術都是真的。」

東西 here refers to magic tools the man who claims to be a magician is selling.

What meaning does 批 add here?

Comment: 批 here means [批發](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%89%B9%E7%99%BC) (wholesale).

Comment: more info, it is related with 'batch' 'bulk', you know there is 'retail', what if you need large amount of something, you probably wont go to terminal reseller, you could go to transaction center or manufacturer directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

批 in here means "purchased at a lot/merchant that has batches of goods in stock - 批發場/商", as opposed to the purchase at the typical/general retail store (商店), which usually carries goods with a limited quantity and costs more.

Comment: As a verb, does it refer to the action of **buying** wholesale, as opposed selling, or either buying or selling depending on context?

Comment: Yes. "東西是哪裡**批來**賣的?" 來 means "coming", combined, 批來 = 買來. Also, note the word 賣 (sell) after 買, so the full action is "buying from the wholesaler and selling through retail (買來 - 賣出).

Comment: This verb might mean "low and cheap" in nature because one can get in large quantity at low price, so please note the satirical tone of the speaker in this context.